# How to concat multiple responses and set all response in an array [React JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am doing an API call which is returning IDs and based on number of ids I am doing another call and trying to combine the responses but I am stuck with async issues.

```
const SearchUser = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getSearchUsers();
        const ids = response.data?.map((user) => user.userId);
        await ids.forEach(async (id) => {
            const result = await getUserInfo(id);
            setUsers(...result);
            // combine result in one state
        });
    } catch (error) {
        setSearching(false);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    SearchUser();
    console.log('Users', Users); // this is empty and runs even before calling api
}, []);
```

How can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all responses, and then set them together with `setRNOUsers`

```js
const SearchUser = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getSearchUsers();
        const ids = response.data?.map((user) => user.userId);
        const responses = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => getUserInfo(id)))
        setRNOUsers(...responses.flatMap(x => x));
    } catch (error) {
        setSearching(false);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    SearchUser();
    console.log('RNOUsers', RNOUsers);
}, []);
```

*Side note, the problem with `console.log('RNOUsers', RNOUsers)` is `setRNOUsers` (initialized by `useState`) is asynchronous. Besides that, your API calls are also asynchronous, so you cannot get values from `RNOUsers` immediately in `useEffect`. If you want to see data in that log, you should wait until the state is updated and your component gets re-rendered with your latest data.*